# Vagrant using docker as provider on MacOS, impossible to mount directory in container

Tags: docker, vagrant, boot2docker

I'm using vagrant instead of let's say docker-compose, as the vagrantfile being a ruby file , it gives more flexibility

My Vagrantfile look like this

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.define "db" do |app|
    app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.image = "postgres:9.5"
      d.name = "myproject_db"
      d.env = {
        'POSTGRES_USER' => "admin",
        'POSTGRES_PASSWORD' => "password",
      }
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "fpm" do |app|
    app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.build_dir = "dockerfiles/php-fpm/"
      d.name="myproject_fpm"
      d.link "myproject_db:db"
      d.volumes = [
        "#{ENV['PWD']}/myproject:/var/www/symfony2",
      ]
    end
  end

end
```

it works perfectly fine when on a Linux hardware host, but it fails on Mac, because `vagrant up --provider docker` is going to launch a intermediate linux box to run docker. So it will fail because the

```
 d.volumes = [
    "#{ENV['PWD']}/myproject:/var/www/symfony2",
 ]
```

takes `#{ENV['PWD']}` from the MacOS machine, but run it on the linux box, so the path does not exist and fails. However I can't put a relative path, because docker needs an absolute one

So is there any workaround for that ? (outside of creating myself a virtualbox on which i then install vagrant and run the command from there)

Answer (score 1):

By default Vagrant Docker provider uses boot2docker for hosting Docker on Windows and MacOS machines. But you can specify your custom Vagrant file for Docker Host VM using vagrant_vagrantfile parameter. That is:

```
d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "../path/to/Vagrantfile"
```

In this Vagrantfile you can configure folder sync (between MacOS and Docker Host VM) to some known absolute path that you can use in your docker volume configuration.

To make it conditional based on Vagrant Host OS you could put it inside IF block:

```
if /darwin/.match(RUBY_PLATFORM)
  #MACOS optional configuration
elsif /mingw|mswin/.match(RUBY_PLATFORM)
  #Windows optional configuration
else
  #everything else, most probably Linux
end
```

Comment: thanks, actually as a workaround, i've done something similar, but manually (i.e setting a first vagrant file, which is mounting my repository and then installing vagrant and docker etc. inside it) your solution as the advantage of making automated :) , I'm going to try it and making it cross-plateform (as i don't want to have a VM when running on linux)

Comment: you can put conditional configuration based on Host OS inside simple IF block like below `if /darwin/.match(RUBY_PLATFORM)`

Comment: Yes I was going with something like that, use  #env{pwd} for linux and an hardcoded absolute path for others.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work on Mac OS X and Vagrant you have two options. I have an example of this for another similar asked question a while ago at https://gist.github.com/andyshinn/8c88974daf8204da32f7.

The important bits here are the `config.vm.synced_folder` lines. If your Vagrant VM supports NFS (boot2docker does not) then you can use NFS. Otherwise, the rsync method will work for machines such as boot2docker.

However, if you are using Vagrant, I would search around the Atlas Vagrant boxes for boot2docker ones that support NFS.